# Setting a variable to the current script's filename

Tags: rebol

How would I set a variable to the name of the currently executing script? For example in VBS, it would look something like this: `name = WScript.ScriptFullName`.

I had tried something similar: `Script: system/options/script` and then I tried to print that variable to the console but it prints "Script" instead of the value of the variable.

The reason for this is that I am trying to read from the script using: `text: read %Script`.

Comment: `system/options/script` should be fine. Please also show us how you tried to print the variable, maybe that's amiss.

Comment: I know system/options/script gets what I want, what iäm asking is how do I set it to a variable and print that variable

Answer (score 4):

It should be just:

```
Script: system/options/script
print Script
```

If you want to print the content of the file, you need to read it first, which can be done like this:

```
print read Script
```

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

If you examine the script object, you'll see this detail

```
>> probe system/script
make object! [
    title: none
    header: none
    parent: none
    path: %/C/Rebol/
    args: none
    words: none
]
```

so you can see that what you really wanted ( I think ) is system/script/title as long as that were provided in the script

Answer (score 0):

The right fields to set should be the Rebol program header fields. You can set them e.g. like this

```
Rebol [
  title: 'myprogram
  file: %program
  content: true
]
probe system/script/header
```

then there is even no need anymore to read the script, as it is already in the content field.